# how to use useState to handle object values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to Hook.
On my project, the const state is an object, with state.boolean = false, and state.number = 1

I have an input box associate with the only the state.number,
so what should my handleChange function be?

```
function handleChange(value){
  setState(value.number)
}
```

is not right.

Thanks so much

Comment: Just have two separate pieces of state that you can update independently.

Comment: is there another solution? For some reason, the state is really hard to separate.

Comment: While you could use an single piece of object state, it may be more elegant and maintainable to use the `useReducer` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer - if you're familiar with Redux the patterns should be familiar

Answer (score 4):

You can still update parts of an object using the `useState` hook and its associated setState functions:

```js
const initialValue = {
  boolean: false,
  number: 1
}

const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

function updateNumberPartOfState = number => {
  setValue({
    ...value,
    number: number
  })
}

function updateBooleanPartOfState = boolean => {
  setValue({
    ...value,
    boolean: boolean
  })
}
```

Or like Andrew Li commented, just have a separate setState value/function pair for each variable:

```js
const [boolean, setBoolean] = useState(false)
const [number, setNUmber] = useState(1)
```

Note: don't actually use `boolean` or `number`, as these are very close to the reserved terms `Boolean` and `Number`, and I'm pretty sure typescript uses the lowercase values as reserved words.

Comment: It works! Thanks sososo much, I really appreaciate that

Comment: glad to help.  usually  its nice to upvote someones answer or mark it as the answer if it helped you.  everyone loves meaningless internet points